# If text box input value changes, validate the field.... but if... Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate a few fields using the formvalidator from formvalidation.io but am running into a few problems using it. I need to find out if a textbox (date,telephone,email) has a value (user filled the textbox out) and validate the field. But if the user does not fill out the textbox, do not validate the field. A user may start to fill out the textbox and then delete its contents and if they do this, the field should not be validated. Can anyone help me out with this?

I have tried a few different techniques such as addEventListener and such but I haven't gotten it exactly how I need it.

Here is an example of what I currently have.

```
   $("#Q_dob_text").change(function () {
    var dob = document.getElementById('Q_dob_text').value;
    if (dob !== '') {
        $('#registry').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                dob: {
                    validators: {
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The value is not a valid date'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And I have also tried variations of this too...

```
 document.getElementById('Q_date_text').addEventListener("keydown", dateFx);
    function dateFx() {
        var date = document.getElementById('Q_date_text');
        if (date !== '') {
            $('#registry').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    date: {
                        validators: {
                            date: {
                                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                message: 'The value is not a valid date'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going wrong is that the `.formValidation` call initializes (binds) the plugin to always validate, so as soon as you've run that code once, it will always keep working (even though a user removes the entered text).

What you really want to do is initialize it once, and update it's validation settings (in the `validators` setting) to make it not validate the `dob` (from your first example) if it's empty. You could do so by calling "updateOption" or "removeField", see the [documentation](http://formvalidation.io/api/#update-option).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I actually used a callback function inside of the validator.